# Docker Stack deployment app does not work

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-swarm

I followed the tutorial at https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted-voting-app/

and went until the end of deploying the stack to swarm nodes. All looks fine however, when i open the :5000 i get can't connect error in the browser.

How do i debug it ?

doing docker node ls prints

```
VSKUMAR-mac:docker-stack vskumar$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
manager   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.13.0   
worker    -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           v1.13.0
```

The output for docker service ls is

```
docker@manager:~$ docker service ls
ID            NAME             MODE        REPLICAS  IMAGE
09zd4pgn550j  vote_db          replicated  0/1       postgres:9.4
pwrp0vwurz43  vote_result      replicated  0/1       dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:before
q1xidl29t4b0  vote_visualizer  replicated  0/1       dockersamples/visualizer:stable
vwkk0si87hd6  vote_redis       replicated  0/2       redis:alpine
vxu7jq60e7ph  vote_worker      replicated  0/1       dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker
zayel2tfj2u4  vote_vote        replicated  0/2       dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before
```

Comment: What are you trying to connect to? And are you sure the whole deployment has finished? What does a `docker service ls` show?

Comment: edited question to include the docker service ls output

Comment: So that shows me that none of the services have started, which would explain why it's not working :)

Comment: and how do i start them, i was hoping they start automatically when i did the deploy

Comment: You just need to wait, it's probably pulling images etc... Could do `docker service logs [SERVICE]` to see the status / if there are errors etc..

Comment: docker@manager:~$ docker service logs vote_result
only supported with experimental daemon

what that means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as johnharris85 indicated it did load up after sometime on its own